# Is it good practice to use empty using statement to close a disposable object in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, dispose, using, webrequest

I'm developing a class that can send fttp requests, it has a utility method that can execute different types of ftp methods:

```
private FtpWebResponse DoFttpRequest(Uri uri, NetworkCredential credentials, string method, string file = null)
{
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Credentials = credentials;
    request.Method = method;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
    {
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(file);
        }
    }

    return (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

As you can see, this methods executes ftp method and returns response stream to the caller. Here is the client method that uses this method to write string contents to a file through ftp:

```
public void WriteToFile(string path, string contents)
{
    var uri = new Uri(path);
    using (var ftpResponse = DoFttpRequest(uri, _credentials, Ftp.UploadFile, contents)) { }
}
```

As you can see, here I'm using empty using statement `using (var ftpResponse = DoFttpRequest(uri, _credentials, Ftp.UploadFile, contents)) { }` to dispose of the received stream. 
Is this a good approach to dispose object like that? Is it even necessary to dispose this stream, since it will probably be disposed by the garbage collector anyway?

Comment: Why do you need a reference to it anyway if you are not going to use it?
I would simply write `DoFttpRequest(new Uri(path), _credentials, Ftp.UploadFile, contents)`

Comment: It is necessary to dispose it. Instead of using you can just do `DoFttpRequest(..).Dispose()`. If you use empty using - no need to declare variable: `using (DoFtpRequest(...)) {}`.

Comment: It seems to me that the question has nothing to do with `ftp` or `webrequest`, it's more about `using` in general

Comment: using = try { whatever } finally { dispose }. Use using... but use it with { } so it's clear what's happening.

Comment: @Marco it is a common convention that if you have several usings linked you only use one set of brackets.

Comment: It just isn't "empty".  C# does not require using { braces } when you write a single statement.  And does not insist that you indent that statement.  Make your code readable to yourself by adding those braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it even necessary to dispose this stream, since it will probably be
>   disposed by the garbage collector anyway

You can use this simple code to see how not disposing response stream might completely break application. I use http request instead of ftp for simlicity of testing, but that applies equally to ftp requests.

```
public class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // this value is *already* 2 by default, set for visibility
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2;
        // replace example.com with real site
        DoFttpRequest("http://example.com");
        DoFttpRequest("http://example.com");
        DoFttpRequest("http://example.com");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static HttpWebResponse DoFttpRequest(string uri) {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("got response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Note that you are not disposing `HttpWebResponse`. What will happen is you will see 2 "got response" messages in console and then application will hang trying to get response 3rd time. That's because concurrent connections limit per endpoint (per host) is 2, so while 2 connections to the host (example.com here) are "in progress" - next connection to the same host will have to wait for them to complete. Because you don't dispose response - those connections will not be "completed" until GC collects them. Until then - your application hangs and then fails by timeout (if `request.Timeout` is set to some reasonable time). All subsequent requests also hang then fail by timeout. If you dispose responses - application will work as expected.

So always dispose things that are disposable. Using block is not necessary, you can just do `DoFtpRequest(..).Dispose()`. But if you prefer empty using - at least don't declare unnecessary variable, just do `using (DoFttpRequest(..)) {}`. One thing to note when choosing between empty using and `Dispose` is the possibility of null being returned by `DoFtpRequest`, because if it will return null - explicit `Dispose` will throw NullReferenceException while empty using will just ignore it (you can do `DoFttpRequest(...)?.Dispose();` if you expect nulls but don't want to use using).

Comment: Calling `Dispose()` will not happen if an exception is thrown. Unless you wrap your call into a try-finally block and call it there. And that is excactly what a using block does for you.

Comment: @thehennyy but here using block is empty. If exception happens inside `DoFttpRequest` - there is nothing to dispose, no value is yet returned. When we have value returned - we immediately dispose it.

Answer (score -2):

What using statement does is actually execute some sort of code and then simply calls the Dispose method. 
That's why u can use it only types inherits from IDisposible interface(in most case)

So you don't really have to use using statement. Just simply call

`DoFttpRequest(uri, _credentials, Ftp.UploadFile, contents)).Dispose()`

If you dont Dispose and object by yourself the ***Garbage Collector*** automatically disposes it after the scope completed.
You don't have to think much about memory when you use high level languages like c#, java ... They are called ***Memory Managed Languages***. They handle thoose kind of staff for you.

Comment: Not really. If the method throws an exception it won't be disposed. That's why he should use "using"

Comment: "Garbage Collector automatically disposes it after the scope completed" Not true, GC can only handle managed ressources. Implementing `IDisposable`  makes only sense for *unmanaged* ressources. You have to call `Dispose`, GC won´t do that for you.

Comment: if you use using statement and you kill the process it won't be disposed either. You must be handling the exceptions. And question is not about exceptions :) or i can simply modify my answer with calling dispose method in finally block... But like i say if you kill the process finally block wont be called

Comment: "But like i say if you kill the process finally block wont be called" True, but if you kill it in the moment you try to call `Dispose` on your own it´ll surely won´t be disposed either. This has nothing to do with if you´re calling `Dipose` self or if you´re using `using`-statement. Killing a process however isn´t part of that question IMO.

Comment: @HimBromBeere After scope completed the reference will be removed. And when there is no reference to that object, gc will take care of the object https://stackoverflow.com/a/1480897/2711861

Comment: But GC won´t call `Dispose`. That´s the whole point of `using`-statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45049/2528063

Comment: If the method throws an exception it won't return anything, hence nothing to dispose. The thing that needs to be handled, however, is that the method might return `null`, which `using` would handle, so the correct call would be `?.Dispose()`. Other than that it is fine.